# CI log_threshold Problem

Tags: codeigniter

`A PHP Error was encountered`

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: log_threshold

Filename: codeigniter/Common.php

Line Number: 246

in my CI Project when i work locally it works fine but when i upload it to server it gives this error
serverlink http://outshinebd.com/sm/
Please some body help me
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

check your config.php file in application/config folder. To me it seems like your config file is missing the following entry

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

the values range from 0-4

Comment: Thanks 
But i tried with that ranges(0-4) but the same problem persist. i also upload the file twice